# Cost - Speech to Text - API Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, price, google-cloud-billing

I am trying to understand the pricing for the Speech to Text API.
Google informs they will charge U$0.006 / 15 second.
Taking the following scenario:

- 60 seconds audio file
- Out of the 60 seconds, 45 seconds will be muted and 15 seconds there will be sound to process

How will I be charged? US$0.006 (only the 15 sec with audio) or US$0.006 x 4 (full audio file)?

Thanks.

Comment: audio data which happens to contain data which results (to human ears) in silence is still audio data. The service will still have to ingest the data (bandwidth cost) and will have to examine it to see whether it contains analysable speech or not (CPU cost). It has to process it either way, so I am fairly sure you would be charged for 60 seconds. If you're unsure, you're probably better off asking Google's support, since their billing process is no more transparent to us as it is to you.

Comment: Tks for the input, ADyson. 
My group and I have the same thought as you, but we just want to make sure.
I did try to ask Google Support and they just sent the link to their pricing and docs about the API. 
Hopefully someone here will have used it and can provide a clear answer to it.

Comment: I wonder if your query was answered by a bot! Sounds like something an AI automated responder would do without understanding the question fully. Your only other option is to try it I suppose - proving the concept, even with repetitions of the experiment, will cost less than $1.

Comment: Don't want to be chagred for silence - use open source engines ;)